# Howto use underscore-data (formerly underscore.query)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm really intrigued by an [underscore mixin](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/wiki/Mixin-Catalog) for data query, [underscore-data](https://github.com/dvv/underscore-data/blob/master/README-rql.md). It would be perfect for a project that I'm currently working on. But either I can't get it to work, or I haven't understood how to use the tool, an [RQL implementation](https://github.com/kriszyp/rql).

```
pc = { 
  columns: [
    {   
      title: "3column-left",
      text: "text",
      image: null
    }   
  ]
}
```

I want to test if **/columns** and **/columns/text** exist. However, I can' get the library to deliver a true or false value. For example, both these queries return the original `pc` object:

```
_.query(pc, 'columns&columns/text')
_.query(pc, 'columns&columns/fubar')
```

It's the same thing when trying to test for a given value. Both these queries return the original object, eventhough the second query shouldn't return anything.

```
_.query(pc, 'columns/title', '3column-left')
_.query(pc, 'columns/title', 'doesntExist')
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're referencing `text` as a property of `columns`, rather than one of `columns`'s elements' properties (`columns` is an array)

In order to get around this you would have to construct your RQL as follows:

```
_.query(pc, 'columns/0/title=3column-left'); // exists
_.query(pc, 'columns/0/title=doesntExist'); // doesn't exist
```

Aside: You can also user regular expressions:

```
_.query(pc, 'columns/0/title=re:left'); // exists
_.query(pc, 'columns/0/title=re:right'); // doesn't exist
```

This approach has the obvious limitation of having to know the array index of the object you wish to query on.

Basic info is available here: https://github.com/dvv/underscore-data/blob/master/README-rql.md, unfortunately without any mention of array access.

**Update**:
It's worth noting that the 3rd parameter in the `_.query` function is used for options so using it like:

```
_.query(pc, 'columns/title', '3column-left')
```

will not produced the effect you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But these queries aren't working. Referencing text as a property of columns isn't the issue. So take the first example in the [underscore-data README](https://github.com/dvv/underscore-data/blob/master/README-rql.md).
`_.query([{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:2}], '(a=1|b=2)') === [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:2}]` . Notice that the query doesn't reference the fact that a=1 OR b=2 should be in the first element in the array. That would defeat the purpose of querying, that purpose being to find that element. So using your queries, I get empty results.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve in your query. What do you mean by "a=1 OR b=2 should be in the first element in the array"?

Comment: Heyya. Right, so the query I gave was the first example in that README. And the query `(a=1|b=2)` is supposed to operate over the data structure `[{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:2}]`. You're saying that I have to know the index in order to query the structure. I'm saying that defeats the purpose of querying. I actually submitted a bug report to the author. [See here](https://github.com/dvv/underscore-data/issues/1). Hope that makes sense. And hopefully the author fixes it, as this would be a great tool to use.

Comment: Gotcha. Yep, I agree this is definitely a limitation. I contacted the author about it recently. Do you know if RQL supports this data structure?

Comment: I don't know too much about RQL yet. But I opened an issue with the author about 2 days ago now. He seems to be looking into it. [See here](https://github.com/dvv/underscore-data/issues/1).

Comment: It doesn't look like the issue you opened covers "array access" (or is that not one of the problems?)

Comment: I don't know if RQL or this implementation provides array access. But that's not really the problem in this case. Here, the query `(a=1|b=2)` on the data structure `[{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:2}]` should produce a result of `{a:1,b:2}`. That's not happening. Just the original data structure is returned, no matter if I use this query `(a=1|b=2)` or this one `(a=10)`. So it sounds like the author is in the middle of fixing it. I would offer to help if I had the time, lol.

Comment: The `(a=10)` thing is definitely a bug, however...:
The first query `(a=1|b=2)` returns the original data structure because that's what it should return. The query asks: give me objects where a = 1, or b = 2. The first and second elements of the original data structure `[{a:1,b:2}, {a:3,b:2}]` both match the query (a:1, b:2 on the 1st, b:2 on the 2nd).

Comment: Yes you are correct. But the fact that the first query `(a=1|b=2)` returns the original data structure because that's what it should return, is just coincidence. With my local copy, I've actually tested  underscore-data against several data structures and queries (incl. the ones up top). And the query is definitely breaking for me.